# heroku custom domain: Host

Tags: heroku, dns

I have some struggles setting up a custom domain for my rails application. I followed the "Summary of steps" on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

For example: i bought the domain "mydomain.com". I added the domain by running `heroku domains:add "www.mydomain.com"`

And gave all Informations shown when running `heroku domains`(Domain Name; DNS Record Type; DNS Target) to my Domain-provider. But it seems like these are not enough informations therefore my provider is asking for a so-called "host" or subdomain, for which the DNS target is to be deposited.

So my question is what is this "host" and why is it needed?

**EDIT:**
So to clarify, the Problem was that i did not really knew what heroku is doing when running `heroku domains:add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Host" probably means the bare domain, i.e. `mydomain.com`, excluding 'www' at the front or anything else.

The subdomain is the bit that comes before that.

In doing `domains:add www.mydomain.com` you are asking heroku to respond to `www.mydomain.com.herokuapp.com`, so you need point your DNS to that.

Hence, on your DNS provider you probably need a CNAME record like `www.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`

That basically means send everything that they receive on your actual domain to that one, instead, which is the one that heroku serves your app on.

Different DNS providers do use slightly different terms, so you need to get the concepts clear of what you're trying to achieve, then you'll work it out. Also, delays in records updating can make it annoying to debug when you're trying to get this working.

Comment: thank you very much, but i got still one question, in doing `domains:add www.mydomain.com` shouldnt my application be reachable under `www.mydomain.com.herokuapp.com` ? because this is not the case

Comment: yes, and that has nothing to with how you set up your own domain on your own dns provider, it doesn't use your own domain at all - it's on heroku's herokuapp domain.  if you go to dashboard and press 'open app' in the top right does it work?

Comment: correction! - sorry, my above comment is wrong. Note the difference between herokuapp.com and herokudns.com.

Comment: To clarify, app is available at `myappname.herokuapp.com`, and dns should point to `www.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`. hopefully i got that right this time! :)

Comment: ok i think i understood, so therefore my Host or subdomain will be `mydomain.com`. thank you very much :)

Comment: *sub* domain is anything you want that comes *before* the domain name that you bought. e.g. 'www' is a subdomain.